# How to transform a If Construct in Java to a Switch Case with Strings or Enum Values?

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml document, that is saved as a string in the variable xmlRequest. I want to check, if a specific xml element is available in this xml document. I have a solution like this, but this a bad solution I would think:

```
if (xmlRequest.contains("<Initial>") && xmlRequestBody.contains("</Initial>")) {
   // do something specific for <Initial> 
}
if (xmlRequest.contains("<Area>") && xmlRequestBody.contains("</Area>")) {
   // do something for <Area>
}
if (xmlRequest.contains("<Circle>") && xmlRequestBody.contains("</Circle>")) {
   // do something for <Circle>
}
```

An If Else construction is bad too, since the number of if cases can be grow up very high. I Think a switch case is the best way to solve this problem, but how can i build it, since a use boolean comparisons too.

Comment: Why don't you use parser?

Comment: I'd use a map and iterate over it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you have one string containing the starting tag and a *different* string containing the ending tag...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using custom code to do XML parsing. That's not usually a good idea, it's better to use a parser. And with some parsers, your structure would change sufficiently that the question would become somewhat irrelevant.

But depending on the parser, the question about code structure (and in particular long lists of `if` or `if...else if`) may remain, so I'll address it:

`if...else if` is the correct construct here, unless it's possible for more than one of the conditions to be true at the same time and you want to do the work in each case. If so, what you have (`if...if`) is the correct construct.

`switch` isn't useful here unless the things you're testing are constants or enums. You're using `contains`, so that doesn't apply. Java doesn't allow expressions in the `case`s, they must be constants or enums ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11)), so `if...else if` or `if...if` is the best you can do with the strings you're using.

Well, no, actually: You could (and if there are *lots* of these, as you say, probably *should*) refactor that code to use the command pattern and a loop, e.g. (pseudocode):

```
TagCommands[] commands = /* ...objects that have the tag name
                               and function to call... */;
for (TagCommands command : commands) {
   if (command.matches(xmlRequest, xmlRequestBody) {
       command.execute(/*...relevant args here...*/);
   }
}
```

...where `TagCommand` looks vaguely like this:

```
interface TagCommand {
    void setTag(String tag);
    String getTag();
    boolean matches(String request, String requestBody);
    void execute(/*...relevant args here...*/);
}
```

...possibly with

```
abstract class TagCommandBase implements TagCommand {

    private String tag;

    TagCommandBase(String tag) {
        this.setTag(tag);
    }

    void setTag(String tag) {
        this.tag = tag;
    }

    String getTag() {
        return this.tag;
    }

    boolean matches(String request, String requestBody) {
        return request.contains("<" + this.getTag() + ">") &&
               requestBody.contains("</" + this.getTag() + ">");
        }
    }
}
```

...and then you create your array of `TagCommand` using concrete implementatons of that per tag that implement `execute` (either declared classes, or anonymous classes).

Comment: You offered him the least dumbest option instead of pointing out the right solution - parser.

Comment: @RanEldan: Using a parser or not (and I agree you should use a parser) doesn't necessarily change the question about code structure and dispatching based on the tag (regardless of how you detect the tag). But yes, some parsers (SAX for instance) would encourage a different solution, I've added a note about that.

Answer (score 3):

In short: You can't use a switch case statement in this case as it can only check value equality.

Anyway you should look into [Java XML parsing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/) instead of doing it yourself.

Answer (score -4):

You need to use at least Java 7 - see the section entitled "Using Strings in switch Statements" at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Nope, switch with strings still just checks equality. OP wants a contains match.